# How to export data from C++ to MatLab

Tags: c++, matlab

I have written a c++ program which outputs a list of random numbers.  I was asked to export these numbers to MatLab in order to produce a histogram and other graphics.  How can I do this?  (I'm a beginner; please specify the extra files and steps I need to add).  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did from the matlab console (`input.txt` contains 3 integers values):

```
>> f=fopen('input.txt','rt')

f =

     3

>> fscanf(f,'%d')

ans =

        1234
       23435
         888

>> fclose(f)

ans =

     0

>>
```

To sum it up:

```
f=fopen('input.txt','rt');
integerList = fscanf(f,'%d');
fclose(f);
```

For more details about the functions you can use `doc` or `help` in the Matlab console:

```
doc fscanf
help fscanf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just print out the numbers into a text file.  If you print them in one line, separated by spaces or commas, you can read them into a 1-D Matlab array using the `load` command.